# Elasticsearch-dsl nested queries

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using the elasticsearch-dsl library in my Django project to index data and then query it back.

I have the following models:

```
class Comments(models.Model):

    comment_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True,null=True)
    user_post_id = models.ForeignKey('UserPosts',null=True)
    score =  models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True,null=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    creation_date = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True,null=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.comment_id

    def indexing(self):


        obj = CommentsIndex(
            meta={'id': self.id},
            comment_id=self.comment_id,
            user_post_id=self.user_post_id,
            score=self.score,
            text=self.text,
            creation_date=self.creation_date,
        )
        obj.save(index='comments-index')
        return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)


class UserPosts(models.Model):

    user_post_id = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)
    user_post_type_id = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)
    accepted_answer_id = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)
    creation_date = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank = True , null = True)
    score = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)
    view_count = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)
    body = models.TextField( blank = True , null = True)
    last_editor_user_id = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)
    last_editor_display_name = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)
    last_edit_date = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)
    last_activity_date =models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)
    answer_count = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)
    comment_count = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)
    favorite_count = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)
    owner_user_id = models.ForeignKey(StackOverFlowUsers,null=True)
    parent_id = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , blank = True , null = True)

    def __unicode__(self):

        return self.user_post_id
```

This is how I wrap my model in a doctype:

```
class UserPostsIndex(InnerDoc):
    user_post_id = Text()
    score = Text()



class CommentsIndex(DocType):
    comment_id = Text()
    user_post_id = Nested(UserPostsIndex)
    score = Text()
    text = Text()
    creation_date = Text()
```

When i call the following function, my data gets indexed into elastic search:

```
def bulk_indexing():
    CommentsIndex.init(index='comments-index')
    es = Elasticsearch()
    bulk(client=es, actions=(b.indexing() for b in models.Comments.objects.all().iterator()))
```

The way I am trying to test if i can query my data back is by using the search function which is as follow:

```
def search(text):
    s = Search(index="comments-index").filter("term",  score= text)
    response = s.execute()
    return response
```

I am unable to query the nested object and have tried a lot of different methods but failed. How can I get the nested object fields for example user_post_id.score?

Answer (score 7):

something like this should work:

```
CommentsIndex.search().query('nested', path='user_post_id', query=Q('range', eser_post_id__score={'gt': 42}))
```

Comment: What is "gt" used for? It does not return me anything though

Comment: The problem might be that the data has not been indexed correctly because the way my foreign keys were setup. Can you please have a look at my other question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252992/error-when-indexing-data-using-elasticsearch-dsl